# How to find a single forumla for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am putting pricing strategy for a product

This product for 1 user is for $100

for 2 user is for $190

for 3 user is for $271

and so on

there for the equation will be

1 user = 100

2 users = $100 + 100\times0.9$

3 users = $100 + 100\times0.9 + 100\times0.9^2$

4 users = $100 + 100\times0.9 + 100\times0.9^2 +  100\times0.9^3$

..

There for for $N$ users the price will be

$N$ users = $100 (1 + 0.9 + 0.9^2 + 0.9^3 + ... + 0.9^N)$

How to put this in a single formula so I do not need to calculate all $N-1$ users first?

Comment: Are you familiar with the sum of a geometric series?

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the *geometric* series $1+r+r^2+\ldots+r^N$ is given by $\frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$ if $r\not=1$ (and by $N+1$ if $r=1$), Thus in your case you may calculate $100\frac{1-0.9^{N+1}}{1-0.9
}=1000({1-0.9^{N+1}})
$.

*Comment*: As mentioned in a comment below $\frac1{0.1}=10$ and not $100$.

Comment: 100 / 0.1 = 1000

Comment: Of course! My fault,

Comment: I believe your $N$ is off by $1$ from the question. (Try $N=1$.)

Comment: You are right, but the formula in the question was given by $1+0.9+\ldots +0.9^N$,

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with the geometric formula. Therefore, you get
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} 100 \cdot 0.9^{k-1} = 100\cdot \frac{1-0.9^{k}}{1-0.9} $$

Comment: When K = 1 the sigma side = 900 while the right side is 100 !! i think it should be k+1

Comment: and still does not cover the case when k = 0

Comment: @asmgx You're right, I made an error, though the error was a different one. It should have been $k-1$ on the right-hand side.  And I think the case k=0 is not necessary in the example above, because it begins at 1.